# Change Query in Firebase Recycvlerview

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

Hey Guys i try to change the Query in Firebase depending on the selected user. But when i update the Query the Recyclerview stops showing data. Below is my Code. I would really appreciate if someone could take a look. I'm using the Recyclerview provided by Firebase. The database I'm using is Firestore.

```
package com.larinet.veikkokrypczyk.myfamilyandfriends;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class LocationListFragment extends Fragment {
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    RecyclerView locationList;
    private static final String TAG = "LocationListFragment";
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private Query query;
    private FirestoreRecyclerOptions<LocationEntity> response;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location_list, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        locationList = view.findViewById(R.id.locationdata_rv);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        locationList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity(currentUser.getDisplayName(), currentUser.getUid());
        getInitialData(user);
    }

    public void getInitialData(UserEntity user){
        //FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here:
        query = db.collection("locations").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).whereEqualTo("id", user.getId());

        response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<LocationEntity>()
                .setQuery(query, LocationEntity.class)
                .build();

        attachRecyclerViewAdapter();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void getLocationDataForUser(UserEntity user){
        //FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here:
        query = db.collection("locations").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).whereEqualTo("id", user.getId());

        response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<LocationEntity>()
                .setQuery(query, LocationEntity.class)
                .build();

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void attachRecyclerViewAdapter() {
        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<LocationEntity, FriendsHolder>(response) {
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(FriendsHolder holder, int position, LocationEntity model) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.locationLat.setText(Double.toString(model.getGeoPoint().getLatitude()));
                holder.locationLong.setText(Double.toString(model.getGeoPoint().getLongitude()));
                holder.userName.setText(model.getUserName());
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm", Locale.GERMAN);
                String time = sdf.format(model.getDate());
                holder.date.setText(time);


                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    Snackbar.make(locationList, Double.toString(model.getGeoPoint().getLatitude())+", "+Double.toString(model.getGeoPoint().getLongitude()), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                });
            }

            @Override
            public FriendsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup group, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, group, false);
                return new FriendsHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
        };
        locationList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public class FriendsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView locationLat;
        TextView locationLong;
        TextView userName;
        TextView date;

        public FriendsHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            locationLat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.locationLat);
            locationLong = itemView.findViewById(R.id.locationLong);
            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `.whereEqualTo("id", currentUser.getUid())` instead of `.whereEqualTo("id", user.getId())`? Can you also add your database structure?

Comment: I already tried that. It doesn't seem to be the query. I will provide the structure later.

Comment: Hi so just to elaborate a bit more on the topic. Initially the Data for the Current User is loaded and displayed. But when someone selects another User this one is passed in here and calls getLocationDataForUser. After That Call there is no Data anymore.

Comment: my firebase structure: there are 2 collections 
locations --> id , date, geoPoint, userName
users --> userName, id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so my Solution now looks like the following:

```
public void getInitialData(UserEntity user){
    //FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here:
    query = db.collection("locations").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).whereEqualTo("id", user.getId());

    response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<LocationEntity>()
            .setQuery(query, LocationEntity.class)
            .build();

    attachRecyclerViewAdapter();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void getLocationDataForUser(UserEntity user){
    adapter.stopListening();
    //FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here:
    query = db.collection("locations").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).whereEqualTo("id", user.getId());

    response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<LocationEntity>()
            .setQuery(query, LocationEntity.class)
            .build();

    attachRecyclerViewAdapter();
    adapter.startListening();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The important part seems to be to stop listening and start listening by your own if you change the query also i need to reinstantiate the Adapter. I honestly don't know if all of this is good practice but it works..